# C++ How to restart an if statement?

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

Say your code is:

```
cout << "You wake up in a room. There is a small lit candle and a door. What do you do?" << endl;
        string startout;
        getline(cin, startout);
            if (startout == "Door" || startout == "DOOR" || startout == "door" || startout == "Open Door" || startout == "open door" || startout == "OPEN DOOR" || startout == "Open door" || startout == "Open the door" || startout == "open the door")  {
                cout << " " << endl;
                cout << "You move to the door but its too dark to see anything besides the outline of it." << endl;
            } else if (startout == "Candle" || startout == "CANDLE" || startout == "candle" || startout == "Pick Up Candle" || startout == "PICK UP CANDLE" || startout == "pick up candle" || startout == "Pick up candle") {
                cout << "You pick up the candle then move to the door. With the light from the candle you can see the door well. What do you do?" << endl;
            };
```

If whoever is using the code types something else besides "Door" or "Candle" (Or any variant), what would the code be to restart the if statement so it re-asks the first question?

Ex: User inputs: "dance"

Output: "I don't understand "dance".
What do you do?"

or something similar.

Comment: So... you want a "loop"

Comment: I was the person helping you on Reddit - this is going to get really ugly as soon as you start applying it to every branch of your tree. You really need to start looking into using a finite state machine instead of a really deep tree of `if` statements.

Comment: You should also just transform your inputs to lowercase, then you only have to compare `startout == "door" || startout == "open door"`, and not every combination of capitalisation.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Or something.  A long list of `if` is definitely _not_ a good way to parse input.  (I didn't go that far in my answer, but if I'm taking a full line of input, I'd start by removing "noise", like `"the"`, and canonizing the input in other ways.)

Comment: @JosephMansfield At first, I read that as "every combination of capitalism" :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a somewhat better parser.  At the very least, put the
legal values in a table or a map of some kind, with a pointer to the
action.  Then wrap the input in a function:

```
typedef void (*     ActionPointer)();  //  Or whatever you need.
typedef std::map< std::string, ActionPointer, CaseInsensitiveCmp >
                    ActionMap;

ActionPointer
getAction( ActionMap const& legalValues )
{
    std::string line;
    if ( ! std::getline( std::cin ) ) {
        //  Error on std::cin...  Probably fatal.
    }
    ActionMap::const_iterator action = legalValues.find();
    return action == legalValues.end()
        ? nullptr
        : action->second;
}
```

Then you can write something like:

```
std::cout << "You wake up in a room. There is a small lit candle and a door."
             " What do you do?" << std::endl;
ActionPointer nextAction = getAction();
while ( nextAction == nullptr ) {
    std::cout << "I don't understand.  What do you do?" << std::endl;
    nextAction = getAction();
}
(*nextAction)();
```

If you want more information in the error message, you can arrange to
return a `struct` with the pointer and that information (still testing
the pointer).

Comment: Looks like an interpreter.... Pretty neat; however, i`m not sure if all the pointers and maps are fit for a person who didn't get to learn loops yet...

Comment: @A.Abramov Maps may be new to him, but he definitely should use them instead of his unwieldy `if`.  The pointer to function may be a bit tricky if you're not used to it.  It's the solution I'd use, but you could just as easily replace it with an `enum` and a `switch`.  The most important point, however, is that this needs to be in at least two different functions.

Comment: Mhm, you convinced me. Although i must mention the `if`s are easily changeable - you can make them look much nicer when it's just these 2 commands.

Comment: @A.Abramov It's a question of lines of code, as well.  No doubt his code is going to grow, and when you start thinking in terms of 5 or 10 commands, the `if` start becoming very unwieldly.  (If I were writing this, I'd put the loop handling errors in a separate function as well, so that I could reuse it in many different contexts, with different lists of actions.  But of course, done this way, rather than a pointer to a function, all you need is the next message and a pointer to the next map.)

Comment: Well said, my thoughts exacly. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `while(true)` loop outside, and add an if condition which breaks upon correct input.

Also, after the getline command, add an else condition after the else if conditon:

```
else
    cout << "I don't understand " << startout << ". What do you do?" << endl;
```

In the other `if` and `else if` clause, add a `break;` command.

Answer (score 0):

You want to run until they type the right thing? That's pretty simple. You should use a loop.

A loop is usually a block of statements which repeats itself until a condition is satisfied. For example, a good loop for you would be:

`Repeat the program until the string equals Door or Candle`.

The condition, I see you are already familier with. Then let me introduce you to the syntax of the block of a `while` loop, which I think is the most fit for your case(`do while` is another loop which is fit for you, but it's slightly more complex to explain).
**EDIT**: I am changing the code with rain's comments:

```
string startout=""; // Initiallizing it before the while loop, so it could be used inside it.
cout << "You wake up in a room. There is a small lit candle and a door. What do you do?" << endl;
while(startout !="door" && startout !="candle") // Do the following actions in this block until startout equals "Door" or "Candle".
{ // start of a while block
    getline(cin, startout);
    if (startout.tolower().find("door")!=npos) // If the string contains any variation of door:
    {
        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << "You move to the door but its too dark to see anything besides the outline of it." << endl;
    } 
    else if (startout.tolower().find("candle")!=npos) // same, with candle. Much more elegant, like thomas said. 
    {
            cout << "You pick up the candle then move to the door. With the light from the candle you can see the door well. What do you do?" << endl;
    }  
    else
    {
       cout << "I don't understand " << startout << ". What do you do?" << endl; // If you didn't get what you want, ask for another string and restart.
    }
} // end of the while block.
```

Comment: You could reduce the `if` statements by transforming the text to all lower case or all upper case.  This would reduce the number of expressions in the `if` statement to 1.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Just did, with a little addition (: great idea.

Comment: Given that long term, he's probably going to want even more different actions, I'd use a map, rather than a succession of `if`.  And I'd definitely put the actual actions outside the loop.

Answer (score -2):

```
for (;;)
    cout << "You wake up in a room. There is a small lit candle and a door. What do you do?" << endl;
    string startout;
    getline(cin, startout);
    if (startout == "Door" || startout == "DOOR" || 
        startout == "door" || startout == "Open Door" || 
        startout == "open door" || startout == "OPEN DOOR" || 
        startout == "Open door" || startout == "Open the door" ||
        startout == "open the door")  {

        cout << " " << endl;
        cout << "You move to the door but its too dark to see anything besides the outline of it." << endl;
        break;
    } else if (startout == "Candle" || startout == "CANDLE" || 
               startout == "candle" || startout == "Pick Up Candle" || 
               startout == "PICK UP CANDLE" || 
               startout == "pick up candle" || 
               startout == "Pick up candle") {
        cout << "You pick up the candle then move to the door. With the light from the candle you can see the door well. What do you do?" << endl;
        break;
    }; 
}
```

Not the most elegant way to do it, but you get the idea.

Comment: Using an endless loop is slightly more than not elegant - he pretty much gave you the term.

Comment: @A.Abramov Oh, come on. This is a command-line based RPG from the look of it. The whole game is meant to be an infinite loop that breaks on some end-game condition. Having this one infinitive loop isn't doing any more damage.

Comment: My point exacly - it's an RPG. Thus he might want to do things after the loop is done. Your solution is not wrong - however, it's also not right.

Comment: @user3109672 You can always rewrite an infinite loop with some breaks into it with a normal loop with a condition - and it's neater to do so.

Comment: @JosephMansfield I'll second that.  And it's far easier to understand and analyse a normal loop with all of its conditions at the top.